# How to customize or omit the Built-By manifest header with Tycho?

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

When using Tycho to build an Eclipse RCP application based on plug-ins, Tycho adds a `Built-By` header with the value of the logged-in user id in the manifest of every plug-in.

How to configure Tycho to either not add this header, or to set a customized value?

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

Comment: @khmarbaise : why? The question should be why do you want to expose some internal information publicly??...We don't want to expose publicly the userid that was loggued (internal data)  when the build is done. simple as that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a way to omit the `Built-By` header, but you can change its value:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version> 
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifestEntries>
            <Built-By>Anonymous</Built-By>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The resulting manifest contains this header:

```
Built-By: Anonymous
```

If you specify an empty manifest entry (using `<Built-By></Built-By>`), an empty header is added to the resulting manifest file.

```
Built-By:
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a feature of the maven archiver that Tycho uses, see [Tycho docs](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/package-plugin-mojo.html#archive)

According to  [maven archiver docs](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html) you can specify to omit the default manifest entries

`<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version> 
      <configuration>
          <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>false</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
          </manifest>
  </configuration>
</plugin>`

Comment: The configuration settings only affect the `Specification-*` and `Implementation-*` headers. The `Built-By` header is still generated.

Comment: right. I guess in this case there is now way to remove the Built-By header and adding an empty Built-By header is your best option for now